# postfix on Linux won't restart after kill postfix-process

Tags: linux, services, postfix

Briefly: I had a problem with `postfix`. That is why I killed the process. Problem now is that I can not start it again.

How can I solve this? And what additional information do you need?

Output from Linux:

```
[root@kcsweb03 /]# postfix restart
-bash: /usr/sbin/postfix: cannot execute binary file
```

or:

```
[root@kcsweb03 /]# service postfix start
Starting postfix:                                          [FAILED]
```

There is nothing interesting in the logs (`maillog`, `messages`, etc)

Comment: Are you root? did you used sudo?

Comment: @Fischer Yes, and yes.